# How to make a frame like below picture?

Tags: framed

Where to find or how to make a frame like  below picture with optional width and height? [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a proposal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Scroll}[3]{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-] (0.25,0) -- (#1,0);
\draw[domain=90:450,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))-1)}+#2);
\filldraw[fill=gray,domain=270:450,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))-1)}+#2) -- (0,{0.25*(-sqrt(1/3)-1)+#2});
\draw[-] (0,#2) -- (#1,#2);
\draw[domain=180:360,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))-1)});
\draw ({-0.5*(sqrt(1/2)},-0.25) -- ({-0.5*(sqrt(1/2)},#2-0.25);
\draw (0.25,-0.25) -- (0.25,#2-0.25);
\draw (0,{0.25*(-sqrt(1/3)-1)+#2}) -- (0,{0.25*(sqrt(1/5)-1)+#2});
\draw[domain=-90:350,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+#1},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+1)}+#2);
\draw ({-0.25+#1},0.25+#2) -- ({-0.25+#1},#2);
\filldraw[fill=gray,domain=-60:350,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+#1},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+1)}+#2); 
\draw[domain=-90:00,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+#1},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+1)});
\draw ({0.25*sqrt(2)+#1},0.25) -- ({0.25*sqrt(2)+#1},#2+0.25);
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cardwidth}{#1 cm-2cm}
\node[text width=\cardwidth,align=center](scrolltext) at (#1/2,#2-1){
\begin{minipage}{#1 cm}
#3
\end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\Scroll{6}{4}{<ho v\`{a} t\^{e}n th\'{i} sinh>\\
Ng\`{a}y sinh}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\Scroll` command takes three arguments: `\Scroll{width}{height}{text}`. In this version, `width` and `height` are to be numbers (rather than lengths).