# How to make this picture in different colors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I found this question with the answer : 
[How to make a frame like below picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410022/how-to-make-a-frame-like-below-picture/410040#410040)

I want to know how I can change it to obtain one like this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\newcommand{\Scroll}[4][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
% shade bulk
\shade[opacity=0.2,upper right=green!30!blue!20!white,lower left=green!30!blue!20!white,
upper left=green!30!blue,lower right=green!30!blue] (0,#3) -- (#2,#3) -- plot[domain=-90:0,smooth,variable=\x] ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+#2},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+1)}+#3)
 -- ++(0,-#3) -- plot[domain=0:-90,smooth,variable=\x] ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+#2},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+1)}) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
% shade upper left
\shade[opacity=0.2,left color=green!30!blue,right color=green!30!blue!50!white] plot[domain=90:450,smooth,variable=\x] ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))-1)}+#3) -- cycle;
% fill white and shade left part
\fill[white] plot[domain=180:360,smooth,variable=\x] 
 ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))},({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))-1)}+#3) --++(0,-#3)
 --plot[domain=360:180,smooth,variable=\x]  ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))-1)}) -- cycle;  
\shade[opacity=0.2,left color=green!30!blue,right color=green!30!blue!50!white] plot[domain=180:360,smooth,variable=\x] 
 ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))},({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))-1)}+#3) --++(0,-#3)
 --plot[domain=360:180,smooth,variable=\x]  ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))-1)}) -- cycle;  
% shade upper right
\shade[opacity=0.2,left color=green!30!blue,right color=green!30!blue!50!white] plot[domain=180:350,smooth,variable=\x] ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+#2},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+1)}+#3)
 -- plot[domain=-60:-90,smooth,variable=\x] ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+#2},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+1)}+#3) -- ++(-0.25,0) -- cycle;
%
\draw[-] (0.25,0) -- (#2,0);
\draw[-] plot[domain=90:450,smooth,variable=\x] ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))-1)}+#3);
% 
\filldraw[fill=gray,domain=270:450,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))-1)}+#3) -- (0,{0.25*(-sqrt(1/3)-1)+#3});
\draw[-] (0,#3) -- (#2,#3);
\draw plot[domain=180:360,smooth,variable=\x] ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/\x))-1)});
\draw ({-0.5*(sqrt(1/2)},-0.25) -- ({-0.5*(sqrt(1/2)},#3-0.25);
\draw (0.25,-0.25) -- (0.25,#3-0.25);
\draw (0,{0.25*(-sqrt(1/3)-1)+#3}) -- (0,{0.25*(sqrt(1/5)-1)+#3});
\draw plot[domain=-90:350,smooth,variable=\x] ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+#2},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+1)}+#3);
\draw ({-0.25+#2},0.25+#3) -- ({-0.25+#2},#3);
\filldraw[fill=gray,domain=-60:350,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+#2},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+1)}+#3); 
\draw[domain=-90:00,smooth,variable=\x] plot ({0.5*cos(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+#2},
 ({0.25*(sin(\x)*(sqrt(90/(\x+180)))+1)});
\draw ({0.25*sqrt(2)+#2},0.25) -- ({0.25*sqrt(2)+#2},#3+0.25);
% text
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cardwidth}{#2 cm-2cm}
\node[anchor=north,text width=\cardwidth,align=center,#1](scrolltext) at
(#2/2,#3-0.2){#4};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\Scroll[font=\sffamily\Large]{6}{4}{turtles and ducks and Italians
and Englishmen and marmots can happily coexist}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what you added please ? thank you very much

Comment: @Vrouvrou I added all the shadings above `\draw[-] (0.25,0) -- (#2,0);`, and made other small adjustments such as the possibility to pass options to the macro.

Comment: Nice message marmot !

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfn4G.png